# Extract one dimension from an n-dimensional InterpolatingFunction

Tags: interpolation

How can I extract a single dimension from an `InterpolatingFunction`? As an example:

```
ClearAll[x];
s = NDSolve[
 Evaluate[Derivative[1][x][t] == -x[t]] && x[0] == {10, -10, 4}, 
   x, {t, 0, 5}]
x = x /. First@s
Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: plot]

I can easily extract values (and also plot) for a single dimension like this

```
x[1][[1]] + x[1][[3]]
(* 5.15031 *)
```

but if I want to create a new function representing the sum? The following generates a lot of warnings.

```
sum = FunctionInterpolation[x[t][[1]] + x[t][[3]], {t, 0, 5}]

(*   Part::partw: Part 3 of 
InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,5.}},{5,3,1,{57},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{}, 
False},{{0.,0.000114457,<<48>>,<<7>>}},{{{10.,-10.,4.},{-10.,10.,-4.}},{ 
{9.99886,-9.99886,3.99954},{-9.99886,9.99886,-3.99954}},{{9.99771,-9.997 
71,3.99908},{-9.99771,9.99771,-3.99908}},{{9.9603,-9.9603,3.98412},{-9.9 
603,9.9603,-3.98412}},<<44>>,{{0.229328,-0.229328,0.0917314},{-0.229328, 
0.229328,-0.0917314}},{{0.194925,-0.194925,0.0779699},{-0.194925,0.19492 
5,-0.0779699}},<<7>>},{Automatic}][t] does not exist. >> 

....  

General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during 
this calculation. >>  **)
```

I have also noticed that

```
x2 = FunctionInterpolation[x[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

appears to throw away all but the first dimension.

```
{x[2], x2[2]} // TableForm

(*    
1.35335 -1.35335    0.541341
1.35335     
*)
```

What is the best way to extract a single dimension from `InterpolatingFunction`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using some *underdocumented* functionality:

```
x = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == {10, -10, 4}}, x, {t, 0, 5}];

pts = Transpose[Append[x["Coordinates"],
                       Total[Drop[x["ValuesOnGrid"], None, {2}], {2}]]];

xsum = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> x["InterpolationOrder"][[1]],
                     Method -> x["InterpolationMethod"]];

Plot[xsum[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: et voilà!]

---

### Taking a vector-valued `InterpolatingFunction[]` apart: A blow-by-blow account

The package [`` DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`​ ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html#120436095) features a number of functions for taking an `InterpolatingFunction[]` apart. The secret behind this package is that there is a built-in, yet undocumented way to extract required parts of an `InterpolatingFunction[]` object, and the functions in this package are but an interface for this.

In the code given above, I used four of these "parts": `"Coordinates"`, which gets the values of the independent variable (`"Grid"` is an alternative); `"ValuesOnGrid"`, which gives the corresponding values of the dependent variable; `"InterpolationOrder"`, the order of the polynomial pieces used in the interpolation; and `"InterpolationMethod"`, which gives the method used for the interpolation.

To use the OP's simpler example of just extracting the first component, here's how it's done. `x["Coordinates"]` gives a list in the form `{{x1, x2, …}}`, while `x["ValuesOnGrid"]` yields a list of the vector values. To get just the first component of each vector, you can do `x["ValuesOnGrid"][[All, 1]]` for this extraction, before massaging it into a nice list of pairs. One such way is

```
x1 = Transpose[Append[x["Coordinates"], x["ValuesOnGrid"][[All, 1]]]]
```

tho as with [list-manipulation](/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) tasks in general, there are a lot of other ways to proceed. You can then feed this to `Interpolation[]`, like so:

```
Interpolation[x1]
```

but to be safe, we have the `InterpolationOrder` and `Method` options be inherited from the original interpolant; thus,

```
Interpolation[x1, InterpolationOrder -> x["InterpolationOrder"][[1]],
              Method -> x["InterpolationMethod"]]
```

Comment: @j-m  I don't understand exactly how this works. Can you simplify the example just to extract a single dimension, like `x[1]`?

Comment: If you can wait a bit, sure...

Answer (score 3):

```
x = NDSolveValue[x'[t] == -x[t] && x[0] == {10, -10, 4}, x, {t, 0, 5}]
y[t_?NumericQ] := x[t][[1]] + x[t][[3]]
sum = FunctionInterpolation[y[t], {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[{x[t], sum@t}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I believe just using `y[t]` should do

Comment: `FunctionInterpolation` has some undocumented options, such as (IIRC) `InterpolationPoints`, that are set to an unacceptably low default. In fact, it *will* lose information about the source interpolation by undersampling. This is especially noticeable, if the soruce function is generally smooth but has subtle features.

Comment: I think just using `y[t]` is better, actually, as the additional `FunctionInterpolation` causes loss of accuracy, especially when the different functions vary at different scales. Still, one ends up evaluating alle the dimensions of the `InterpolatingFunction`, which might not be necessary.