# Plot components of vector valued InterpolatingFunction

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I am very confused with how the Plot command evaluates arguments for vector valued numerical functions. For example, when I run the following commands

```
Clear[f]
f = Interpolation[{{0, {0, 0}}, {1, {1, 2}}}]
Plot[f[t][[2]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

I get the error: `Part::partw: Part 2 of InterpolatingFunction[{{0,1}},{5,3,0,{2},{2},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{0,1}},{{{0,0}},{{1,2}}},{Automatic}][t] does not exist.`.

It seems like the Plot command is trying to evaluate `U[t][[2]]` at some point instead of only calling `U` for specific numeric values. How can I force Plot to only plug evaluate `U` with actual numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[f[t]][[2]], {t, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110377/1871

Answer (score 2):

I still want to see what other answers, but I have found an inelegant solution:

```
Clear[f, ff]
f = Interpolation[{{0, {0, 0}}, {1, {1, 2}}}]
ff[x_?NumericQ, i_] := f[x][[i]]
Plot[Table[ff[t, i], {i, 1, 2}], {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

The key was to make ensure that the placeholder function `ff[t,i]` is not evaluated when `t` is anything but a number. I don't like having to define an extra pattern rule, and I hope this can be done using some combination of `Hold`, `Defer`, `Evaluate`, etc.

Comment: This is, in fact, a typical solution, explained [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4999).  See "Plotting" at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) instead of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
Clear[fff]
fff = Interpolation[{{0, {0, 0}}, {1, {1, 2}}, {2, {3, 2}}, {3, {1, 4}}}];
GraphicsRow@{
  Plot[Indexed[fff[t], 1], {t, 0, 1}], 
  Plot[Indexed[fff[t], 2], {t, 0, 1}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks this is great! `Indexed` is basically exactly what I wanted: a delayed form of `Part`. If only it weren't so hard to find these things in the documentation!