# Problem with the plots of eigenvalues of the Matrix

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I am trying to plot the eigenvalues of the following matrix

```
hamil[kx_,ky_,kz_]={{-10.6`, -0.25` E^(
    I (-0.625` kx - 0.21650635094610965` ky - 
       0.43666666666666665` kz)) - 
   0.7` E^(I (0.375` kx - 0.21650635094610965` ky - 
       0.43666666666666665` kz)) - 
   0.25` E^(
    I (-0.125` kx + 0.649519052838329` ky - 0.43666666666666665` kz)),
   E^((0.` + 
      0.43666666666666676` I) kz) (-0.25` E^((0.` - 
          0.125` I) kx - (0.` + 0.649519052838329` I) ky) + 
     E^((0.` - 0.625` I) kx + (0.` + 
          0.21650635094610965` I) ky) (-0.25` - 
        0.7` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx)))}, {E^((0.` - 
       0.375` I) kx - (0.` + 0.649519052838329` I) ky + (0.` + 
       0.43666666666666665` I) kz) (-0.25` E^((0.` + 0.5` I) kx) + 
     E^((0.` + 0.8660254037844386` I) ky) (-0.7` - 
        0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx))), -10.6`, 
  E^((0.` - 0.5` I) kx - (0.` + 0.43301270189221935` I) ky - (0.` + 
       0.43666666666666665` I) kz) (-0.25` - 
     0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx) - 
     0.7` E^((0.` + 0.5` I) kx + (0.` + 
          0.8660254037844387` I) ky))}, {E^((0.` - 
       0.375` I) kx - (0.` + 0.21650635094610965` I) ky - (0.` + 
       0.43666666666666676` I) kz) (-0.7` - 
     0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx) - 
     0.25` E^((0.` + 0.5` I) kx + (0.` + 0.8660254037844386` I) ky)), 
  E^((0.` - 0.43301270189221935` I) ky + (0.` + 
       0.43666666666666665` I) kz) (-0.7` + 
     E^((0.` - 0.5` I) kx + (0.` + 
          0.8660254037844387` I) ky) (-0.25` - 
        0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx))), -10.6`}}
```

Now the eigenvalues as function of kx, ky and kz are

```
{es1[kx_, ky_, kz_], es2[kx_, ky_, kz_], es3[kx_, ky_, kz_]} = 
  Eigenvalues[hamil[kx, ky, kz]] // FullSimplify;
```

Now plotting all the three eigenvalues

```
Plot[{Chop[es1[0, 0, z]], Chop[es2[0, 0, z]], Chop[es3[0, 0, z]]}, {z,
   0, \[Pi]/1.31}]
```

[image]

I don't understand why is there a sudden jump in blue plot and green plot? Is there a way to rectify this? Is this problem also occur when solving eigenfunctions?

To further stating the problem, as Bob's answer suggests that changing the precision of the equation helps somewhat. However, changing the plotting variable results in same issue that is not rectified by the Bob's solution.

```
Plot[{Chop[es1[x, 0, 0]], Chop[es2[x, 0, 0]], Chop[es3[x, 0, 0]]}, {x,
0, \[Pi]/1.31}]
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (Ver 12.0.0 on OSX 10.15.7).

Comment: @march I missed _ in front of kz in hamil function. Please check that one. I made the edits.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the error (directly copying and running your code)!  What version are you using?

Comment: I am running in Ver 12.1.1  on OSX 11.5.2

Comment: That's strange!  To my understanding, `Root` objects automatically sort the eigenvalues (although all I could find in the documentation was "The ordering used by `Root[f,k]` takes real roots to come before complex ones"), so I'm surprised it's doing this.

Comment: With v12.3.1 the crossovers don't occur. However, with versions that do, this is equivalent to the question that you asked [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/255339/9362)

Comment: @BobHanlon. I'm not sure that it's equivalent, because in the previous post, the eigenvalues cross, and *switch* where they cross, whereas here, they're switching at some arbitrary position.

Comment: @march you are right, in the previous post it was a feature, but in this case I think there is some problem of precision of floating numbers, but I am not sure.

Comment: Does it still occur if don't `FullSimplify` or if you `Rationalize` either `hamil` or the eigenvalue functions?

Comment: @march it does, I have tried it. However, if I used SetPrecision to 10, then it doesn't happen. However, if I change arguments [0,0,z] to [x,0,0], the problem remains.

Comment: @BobHanlon Can you redo the calculation in v12.3.1 for the matrix above with the floating numbers are in machine precision. If you don't get these crossing, I believe its the bug then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reevaluating with v12.3.1, I am able to reproduce the crossover.

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

hamil[kx_, ky_, kz_] = 
   {{-10.6`, -0.25` E^(I (-0.625` kx - 0.21650635094610965` ky - 
           0.43666666666666665` kz)) - 
     0.7` E^(I (0.375` kx - 0.21650635094610965` ky - 
           0.43666666666666665` kz)) - 
     0.25` E^(I (-0.125` kx + 0.649519052838329` ky - 
           0.43666666666666665` kz)), 
    E^((0.` + 
          0.43666666666666676` I) kz) (-0.25` E^((0.` - 0.125` I) kx - (0.` + 
              0.649519052838329` I) ky) + 
       E^((0.` - 0.625` I) kx + (0.` + 0.21650635094610965` I) ky) (-0.25` - 
          0.7` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx)))}, {E^((0.` - 0.375` I) kx - (0.` + 
           0.649519052838329` I) ky + (0.` + 
           0.43666666666666665` I) kz) (-0.25` E^((0.` + 0.5` I) kx) + 
       E^((0.` + 0.8660254037844386` I) ky) (-0.7` - 
          0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx))), -10.6`, 
    E^((0.` - 0.5` I) kx - (0.` + 0.43301270189221935` I) ky - (0.` + 
           0.43666666666666665` I) kz) (-0.25` - 0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx) - 
       0.7` E^((0.` + 0.5` I) kx + (0.` + 
              0.8660254037844387` I) ky))}, {E^((0.` - 0.375` I) kx - (0.` + 
           0.21650635094610965` I) ky - (0.` + 
           0.43666666666666676` I) kz) (-0.7` - 0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx) - 
       0.25` E^((0.` + 0.5` I) kx + (0.` + 0.8660254037844386` I) ky)), 
    E^((0.` - 0.43301270189221935` I) ky + (0.` + 
           0.43666666666666665` I) kz) (-0.7` + 
       E^((0.` - 0.5` I) kx + (0.` + 0.8660254037844387` I) ky) (-0.25` - 
          0.25` E^((0.` + 1.` I) kx))), -10.6`}};
```

The [`Eigenvalues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html) are

```
{es1[kx_, ky_, kz_], es2[kx_, ky_, kz_], es3[kx_, ky_, kz_]} =
  Eigenvalues[hamil[kx, ky, kz]];
```

Plotting shows the crossover:

```
Plot[{Chop[es1[0, 0, z]], Chop[es2[0, 0, z]], Chop[es3[0, 0, z]]},
 {z, 0, π/1.31},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{es1, es2, es3}, {.2, .3}]]
```

[image]

However, using arbitrary-precision instead of machine precision:

```
{es1p[kx_, ky_, kz_], es2p[kx_, ky_, kz_], es3p[kx_, ky_, kz_]} = 
  Eigenvalues[SetPrecision[hamil[kx, ky, kz], 15]];

Plot[{Chop[es1p[0, 0, z]], Chop[es2p[0, 0, z]], Chop[es3p[0, 0, z]]}, {z, 
  0, π/1.31},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{es1, es2, es3}, {.2, .3}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Explicitly [`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) the [`Eigenvalues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html) and use [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{args},
   args = ReplacePart[{0, 0, 0}, var -> t];
   es[t_] = Eigenvalues[
     SetPrecision[hamil @@ args, prec]];
   data = Transpose[Table[Sort@Chop@es[t], {t, 0, 100 Pi/131, Pi/131}]];
   ListLinePlot[data,
    DataRange -> {0, 100 Pi/131},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
       {{"kx", "ky", "kz"}[[var]], 
        "es"}),
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotLegends ->
     Placed[{es1, es2, es3}, {.9, .55}]]] // Quiet,
 {{var, 3, "Plot variable"},
  {1 -> "kx", 2 -> "ky", 3 -> "kz"}},
 {{prec, MachinePrecision, "Precision"}, {MachinePrecision, 15}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is what I am talking about, now if you try ```Plot[{Chop[es1p[x, 0, 0]], Chop[es2p[x, 0, 0]], Chop[es3p[x, 0, 0]]}, {x, 0, π/1.31}]```, you will again get the same problem.